# Best way to embed a csv-File in my application

Tags: c++

I have a program that reads a csv-file at startup. Originally, I thought that it would be useful to change the program behavior without having to recompile it. However, it turned out that a change to the file required a new version of the program to be deployed.

- The csv-file contains a lot of numbers that are internally stored as `std::map<SomeId, std::vector<double/int>>` and accessed via functions like `double get(SomeId id, size_t idx)`
- The file is regularly viewed and modified by non-programmers. They use Excel to do that. Therefore I want to keep the file as "source" of the program.
- I only use Windows as OS. There is no need for other platforms.

Now I think about embedding the content of the file into the program. Here are some alternatives I have thought about:

- Embed the file as Text-Resource and using `LoadResource` etc to get a `std::string` or something like that and parse that text and populate my data structures.
- Write a simple code-generator that creates `char const * const text = "<the content of the file>;`, parse that text and populate my data structures.
- Write a more complicated code-generator that parses the csv and initializes the data structures directly

  ```
  std::map<SomeId, std::vector<double>> initialize()
  {
    std::map<SomeId, std::vector<double>> data; 
    data[id1] = std::vector<double> { ... the numbers from the file ... };
    ...
    return data;
  }
  ```
- Dump the data structures and generate the get-functions directly:

  ```
  std::array<double, N> const data1 { ... the numbers from the file ... };
  double get(SomeId id, size_t idx)
  {
    switch(id)
    {
      case id1 : return data1[idx];      
      case id2 : return data2[idx];
      ...
    }
  }
  ```

Which technique should I use? Have I missed anything?

Comment: I don't do much at all on windows and less linking office documents to code, but wasn't this the whole purpose of OLE (Object Linking & Embedding)? I would think that MS would have a specific library that would allow a hopefully, fairly seamless way of doing exactly this. The only quirk would seem to be if the non-programmers editing the Excel file could change the structure (rows/cols, etc..) that may give your code fits. Like [C++ and OLE Programming Concepts | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/multimedia/c---and-ole-programming-concepts)?

Comment: Does the file contain both the `SomeId` and the numbers?

Comment: If you need to change the logic of the program every time the text of the CSV change, I'd question whether C++ is the correct langue to write what is effectively a run-once program. Have you considered Perl or Python?

Comment: @Caleth: yes, the file(s) contain the IDs and the numbers

Comment: @user31601: a change to the csv is a new version of the app so the whole app has to be built.